# Remote link on isolated rails plugin not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have problems to add remote links to an isolated rails plugin.
When I click on the link, it does nothing.
I don't even get any error messages, it just does nothing.

This is the link:

```html
<!-- app/views/my_plugin/models/new.html.erb -->
...
<fieldset id="attrs">
  <legend><%= t 'my_plugin.attrs' %></legend>
<%= link_to t('my_plugin.new_attr'), models_add_attr_url, :remote => true %>
</fieldset>
...
```

This is my route:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
MyPlugin::Engine.routes.draw do  
...
  get 'models/add_attr'
end
```

This is my controller:

```rb
# app/controllers/my_plugin/models_controller.rb
require_dependency "my_plugin/application_controller"

module MyPlugin
  class ModelsController < ApplicationController
...
    # GET /models/add_attr
    def add_attr
      respond_to { |format| format.js }
    end
...
  end
end
```

This is my js file, just a test:

```js
// app/views/my_plugin/models/add_attr.js.erb
console.log('hello');
```

This is my engine:

```rb
# lib/my_plugin/engine.rb
module MyPlugin
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    require 'jquery-rails'
    require 'turbolinks'
    isolate_namespace MyPlugin
  end    
end
```

This is my gemspec:

```rb
# my_plugin.gemspec
...
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
...
  spec.add_dependency "rails", "~> 5.2"
  spec.add_dependency 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3'
  spec.add_dependency 'turbolinks', '~> 5.2'
...
end
```

I hope I have provided enough info. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have already fixed this bug by filling onclick event at the link with a method which calls rails by ajax. But I still want to know why links with data-remote don't work.